# Not able to download log files using API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When i run below command, it is getting unable parse to filter from myside. I got alert 2nd day log feed down for SL logs. Please help me for this issue.

```
[root@syslogserver ~]# curl -X GET -u username:password -g https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Event_Log/getAllObjects.json?objectFilter={"eventCreateDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":"2016-08-22t15:45:02.476"},{"name":"endDate","value":"2016-08-23t12:27:59.538"}]}}&resultLimit=0,500 [1] 21905

[root@syslogserver ~]# {"error":"Unable to parse object filter.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}{"error":"Unable to parse object filter.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}{"error":"Unable to parse object filter.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}{"error":"Unable to parse object filter.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}{"error":"Unable to parse object filter.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that the ampersand characters in your command are being treated as the bash syntax which runs commands in the background. This causes "resultLimit=0,500" to be discarded. This is what this bit of text is all about: " [1] 21905"

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to apply objectFilter in **eventCreateDate** property. My apologies for the inconveniences. I will let you know if there is a plan to fix it.

Probably it will be possible to filter using a programming language, take a look the programming languages supported by SoftLayer:

[SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)